# How to keep active a runnable thread when an activity is closed but destroy the thread when the activity start again

Tags: android, runnable

I have a runnable thread in one of my activities, which starts when the activity starts. I want to keep the thread running even when my activity is finished, and I want to destroy the thread when the same activity starts again. Is this possible or do I have to try new approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: Something's fishy. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have more than one activity.In one of my activity I implement a runnable thread.If that activity is closed, I don't want to destroy the runnable thread. But I want to destroy this thread when my activity start again... @dmon

Comment: What does the thread do?

Comment: I update the wallpaper through that thread simultaneously. @Squonk

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a service. They live as long as you want them to

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //stop thread
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    //start thread (again)
}
```

}

You have to declare your service in your manifest

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
```

Start and stop your service with

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

If you want to check if your service is running you can use this code

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}