# keeping a thread alive when changing activity

Tags: android, multithreading, background-task

I use AsynTask in my project and execute some task,but when I change my activity , my background task stop. 
Now how can keep my thread alive when my activity change ?

**My Class:**

```
private class mytask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AlertDialog.Builder>{
    Context contex;
    mytask(Context contex)
    {
         this.context = context
    }

        protected AlertDialog.Builder doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(context ,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Tittle");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Message");


            return alertDialog;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AlertDialog.Builder Builder) {
            super.onPostExecute(Builder);
            Builder.show();
        }
}
```

**MainClass :**

```
    new mytask(this).execute() 

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewClass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674763/how-to-keep-active-a-runnable-thread-when-an-activity-is-closed-but-destroy-the

Comment: Your thread is just fine, that is your Context. You are trying to show alert dialog with a context, which is not available anymore after you change activity

Comment: @Nilesh_Rathod  I edit my code Now How Can I extend a class from services and Asynctask both???

Comment: @ Vladyslav_Matviienko  thanks for Comment, but think thread task is coorrect a nd can execute every where

Comment: Sure, it can, but it won't show the alert dialog exactly for the reason I said: your context may become unavailable to show the dialog if foreground activity has changed.

Comment: How can I know my thread is running in new thread?!

Comment: are you trying to show a alertdialog or the thread is meant to do something different?

Comment: So I edit it to do Something else, Now in the second activity how can I know my thread is running !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the background tasks you should use Thread or Service. So your background task will not end after activity change.